# Modifying a global variable in a constexpr function in C++17

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr

In C++17, are you allowed to modify global variables in a `constexpr` function?

```
#include <iostream>

int global = 0;

constexpr int Foo(bool arg) {
    if (arg) {
        return 1;
    }
    return global++;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << global;
    Foo(true);
    std::cout << global;
    Foo(false);
    std::cout << global;
}
```

I wouldn't expect you to be able to, but clang 6 allows it: https://godbolt.org/g/UB8iK2

GCC, however, doesn't: https://godbolt.org/g/ykAJMA

Which compiler is correct?

Comment: @AnT • I need a cheatsheet to keep the C++11, C++14 and C++17 constraints straight.

Comment: Neither work if you force compile time evaluation `constexpr int a = Foo(false)` but I am unsure if which, if either, is incorrect.

Comment: It just seems like a basic bug in gcc to me

Comment: Definitely gcc bug, submitted [86327](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86327)

Comment: Interesting to note is that clang doesn't allow the function to be evaluated as a constant expression on the branch that does the modification of `global` (as noted by @user975989), and if you remove the `if (arg) return 1;` branch it will fail to compile at all, despite still meeting the requirements listed in @codekaiser 's answer.

Comment: @JohnIlacqua: At least the first part is not surprising at all because allowing this would violate the "modification of an object" bullet point in [expr.const].

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Which compiler is correct?

Clang is right.

The definition of a `constexpr` function as per [dcl.constexpr/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.constexpr#3)

> The definition of a `constexpr` function shall satisfy the following
>   requirements:
>   (3.1) its return type shall be a literal type;
>   (3.2) each of its parameter types shall be a literal type;
>   (3.3) its function-body shall be `= delete`, `= default`, or a compound-statement
>   that does **not** contain:
>   (3.3.1) an asm-definition,
>   (3.3.2) a goto statement,
>   (3.3.3) an identifier label,
>   (3.3.4) a try-block, or
>   (3.3.5) a *definition* of a variable of non-literal type or of *static* or
>   thread storage duration or for which no initialization is performed.

Also as per [dcl.constexpr/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.constexpr#5):

> For a `constexpr` function or constexpr constructor that is neither
>   defaulted nor a template, if *no argument values exist* such that an
>   invocation of the function or constructor **could be** an evaluated
>   subexpression of a core constant expression,

`Foo(true)` could be evaluated to a *core constant expression* (i.e `1`).

Also, `Foo(false)` *could be* but is not required to be constant evaluated.

**CONCLUSION**

Thus, a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86327) in GCC.

---

Many thanks to @Barry, @aschepler and @BenVoigt for helping me with this answer.

Comment: It's definitely clearer.  I believe it's actually impossible for the compiler to reason about the value of `global` even if it inlines `Foo(false)` into main, because `global` has external linkage.  (The output does not need to be `0\n0\n1`, because some global constructor in another compilation unit may change `global`)  Therefore, its runtime side effects have to be preserved.

Comment: Although I'm buying your explanation, this may actually be a defect, or at least ambiguity in the standard which the GCC guys fell for. dcl.constexpr/7 states _"...same result as non-constexpr...except can appear in a constant expression"_. Now, `Foo(false)` obviously _can't_ appear in a constant expression, so... that may be why.

Comment: Would you care to add some explanation as to what's supposed to happen for the OP's example, in non–standardese-gibberish? I'm inclined to say what we have here is most of all a _bug in the specification_, not to make it illegal. But perhaps I just haven't understood `constexpr` well enough.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I'll try. `global` may or may not be modified in other translation units due to its linkage and it's not explicitly defined as `const` *by the programmer*. If the compiler can evaluate the expression during compile time it will; but *doesn't mean it should*. Thus, in my own opinion, having a non-tight clause (could but not required), is better.  See also Ben Voigt's comment.

Comment: @Damon, true `Foo(false)` *can't appear* in a constant expression. Supporting your statement, in the code given, it's just a function call (not a constant expression). Unlike if you do `constexpr int i = Foo(false);`, this will prompt the [diagnostic message](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KSxBz23tSpVbkQjp) using Clang.

Answer (score 3):

I'll add that dcl.constexpr/5 additionally requires:

> For a constexpr function or constexpr constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression, or, for a constructor, a constant initializer for some object ([basic.start.static]), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Since you deiberately wrote the function so that `Foo(true)` evaluates to a core constant expression,  `Foo(false)` is not required to.